# UITableViewCell header display drawing issue with NSFetchedResultsController delegate using NSManagedContextDidSaveNotification implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have implemented an `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate with `NSManagedContextDidSaveNotification` to push managed objects changes from another `NSManagedObjectContext` connected to a common `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

When the managed objects are first batch imported and after the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods are called, the result of the cell drawing contains a section that looks like this:

[image]

It is basically a display/drawing bug where a section header gets drawn into a cell. That header and cell are actual valid header and cell that appear further down.

It only happens the first time managed objects are created in batch.  If I restart the app and the managed objects are already imported the controller displays everything fine so it's likely something to do with the import process, which is just the typical `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` implementation (pasted below):

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [_tableView beginUpdates];
}
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:
     (id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo 
     atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex 
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [_tableView insertSections:
                [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [_tableView deleteSections:
                [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            NSLog(@"change section"); break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            NSLog(@"move setion"); break;
    }
}
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
    didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] 
            atIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSLog(@"change object"); break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] 
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            NSLog(@"move object"); break;
    }
}
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [_tableView endUpdates];
}
```

The thing is I tried just implementing a refresh with `needsLayout` and `reloadData` by detecting when it's a first batch import and calling them doesn't get rid of this display issue.  HALP!

EDIT:

```
 - (void)setupFetchedResultsController {
    NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Object"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"attribute" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"attribute2" ascending:YES];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.relationship.attribute3 == true"];
    [fr setPredicate:predicate];
    [fr setSortDescriptors:@[sd1, sd2]];
    _frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fr managedObjectContext:_moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"attribute" cacheName:nil];
    [_frc setDelegate:self];
    NSError *error; if (![_frc performFetch:&error]) NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}
```

EDIT: Here is the code that fixed the issue:

```
- (void)subscribeToNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
      selector:@selector(mergeManagedObject:) 
      name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
      object:nil];
}
- (void)mergeManagedObject:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // This block needed to be sent on the main thread!
        [_managedObjectContext 
          mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try implementing/adjusting your code as follows?

- call `- reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` when `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` on section changes,
- `- moveSection:toSection:` when `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` happens on section changes,
- `- moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`  when `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` is triggered on `controller:didChangeObject:`, and
- `- reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`  when `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` is triggered on `controller:didChangeObject:`.

If that doesn't help, step into those methods and look on what thread they're called. Often, view bugs happen when view updates are called on threads other than the main thread.

Last, did you try using childContexts?

Comment: Nice catch, my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods were being called on the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` dispatch thread, which isn't the main thread.  I made sure to call my `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` handler method on main thread and everything got fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When trying the solution with `reloadData` you can first `nil` out the fetched results controller and have it be recreated lazily. It should then correctly rebuild everything from scratch.

Also, you should eliminate the height manipulation **after** you end the table view updates. There are very rare cases where you have to adjust the content height of your table view manually - why do you think you have to do it here?

Also, you should check all methods in your controller that messes with the height of the cells and sections.

Comment: I removed that so it's less confusing, but it's a non-factor which I tried adding and removing.  Also I had tried to `performFetch:error` before `reloadData`.  I didn't try to set to `nil` first though.  Will try and keep posted.

Comment: The height manipulation code I just edited out is because the table content isn't properly adjusted after the initial import so it's just to be safe.  I know I'm not supposed to need to.

Comment: I tried to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` with `_frc = nil; [self setupFrc]; [_tableView reloadData];` but no good.

Comment: Why do you have setupFrc? Use the plain vanilla code Apple provides in the templates and have the FRC be created lazily.

Comment: I don't know which vanilla code you're talking about, but I don't think that changes anything.  Setting up the fetch request and instantiating the frc isn't really the problem unless you think that is why the cell drawing is messed up.

Comment: Plain vanilla is the code that you find in Apples Xcode templates. (New Project -> Master Detail , check Core Data). If you are introducing new non-standard code an not showing it, my only recourse is to guess where the error lies. It is likely that you are trying to manipulate cell height either there or elsewhere. Thanks for the down-vote - this is how you show appreciation for our efforts.

Comment: I was checking to see if you down voted me.  I added the code for the NSFetchedResultsController setup.  I do appreciate the help, but I have no idea why my question gets down voted for